# How to use WinForms progress bar?

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

I want to show progress of calculations, which are performing in external library.

For example if I have some calculate method, and I want to use it for 100000 values in my Form class I can write:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }            

    private void Caluculate(int i)
    {
        double pow = Math.Pow(i, i);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Maximum = 100000;
        progressBar1.Step = 1;

        for(int j = 0; j < 100000; j++)
        {
            Caluculate(j);
            progressBar1.PerformStep();
        }
    }
}
```

I should perform step after each calculation. But what if I perform all 100000 calculations in external method. When should I "perform step" if I don't want to make this method dependant on progress bar? I can, for example, write

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void CaluculateAll(System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar progressBar)
    {
        progressBar.Maximum = 100000;
        progressBar.Step = 1;

        for(int j = 0; j < 100000; j++)
        {
            double pow = Math.Pow(j, j); //Calculation
            progressBar.PerformStep();
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CaluculateAll(progressBar1);
    }
}
```

but I don't want to do like that.

Comment: Pass a delegate object to the method.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

I would suggest you have a look at [BackgroundWorker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=netframework-4.7.1).  If you have a loop that large in your WinForm it will block and your app will look like it has hanged.

Look at `BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress()` to see how to report progress back to the UI thread.

For example:

```
private void Calculate(int i)
{
    double pow = Math.Pow(i, i);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
    progressBar1.Step = 1;
    progressBar1.Value = 0;
    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var backgroundWorker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    for (int j = 0; j < 100000; j++)
    {
        Calculate(j);
        backgroundWorker.ReportProgress((j * 100) / 100000);
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

private void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: do something with final calculation.
}
```

Comment: Nice example, but there's a small error in your code. You need to set the backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress to true. Check my edit

Comment: @mana The assumption is that the `BackgroundWorker` is added via the designer and configured there.  But yes, it will need to be configured to have `WorkerReportsProgress` set to `true`.

Comment: ah, my bad, did not know that you could set it in the designer

Comment: Wondering something else though, your example only counts to 99         backgroundWorker.ReportProgress((j * 100) / 100000);
how to get 100 % count

Comment: @mana If you want to show the 100% in the progress, do it in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler, if your `DoWork` handler doesn't do it..

Comment: actually, i came up with a fix. After the loop, i report 100, which gives me the 100 % status

Comment: I had a problem with threading and must include: progressBar1.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage; })); in the backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged method

Answer (score 95):

Since .NET 4.5 you can use combination of [**async** and **await**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) with [**Progress**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692(v=vs.110).aspx) for sending updates to UI thread:

```
private void Calculate(int i)
{
    double pow = Math.Pow(i, i);
}

public void DoWork(IProgress<int> progress)
{
    // This method is executed in the context of
    // another thread (different than the main UI thread),
    // so use only thread-safe code
    for (int j = 0; j < 100000; j++)
    {
        Calculate(j);

        // Use progress to notify UI thread that progress has
        // changed
        if (progress != null)
            progress.Report((j + 1) * 100 / 100000);
    }
}

private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
    progressBar1.Step = 1;

    var progress = new Progress<int>(v =>
    {
        // This lambda is executed in context of UI thread,
        // so it can safely update form controls
        progressBar1.Value = v;
    });

    // Run operation in another thread
    await Task.Run(() => DoWork(progress));

    // TODO: Do something after all calculations
}
```

Tasks are currently the preferred way to implement what `BackgroundWorker` does.

> Tasks and `Progress` are explained in more detail here:
>
> - [Async in 4.5: Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/)
> - [Reporting Progress from Async Tasks](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/reporting-progress-from-async-tasks.html) by Stephen Cleary
> - [Task parallel library replacement for BackgroundWorker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513432/task-parallel-library-replacement-for-backgroundworker)

Comment: This should be the selected answer, IMO.  Great answer!

Comment: Almost almost the nicest answer, except that it is using Task.Run instead of a normal async function

Comment: @KansaiRobot You mean as opposed to `await DoWorkAsync(progress);`? This is very much on purpose, as that would not result in an extra thread running. Only if `DoWorkAsync` would call it's own `await` for e.g. waiting on an I/O operation, would the `button1_Click` function continue. The main UI thread is blocked for this duration. If `DoWorkAsync` is not really async but just a lot of synchronous statements, you don't gain anything.

Comment: System.Windows.Controls.ProgressBar doesn't contain contain a field "Step". It should be removed from the example; especially since it isn't used anyway.

Comment: @RobertTausig It's true that `Step` is available only in WinForms' progress bar and is not needed here, but It was present in the question's example code (tagged winforms), so may be it could stay.

Comment: very nice answer and very sound responses to the comments! Thank YOU!

Comment: `Progress` is unnesscery, using `Invoke` instead.

Comment: I still get the error "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'progressBar1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on" and copied the exact snipped. Do I need to set something else for the progressBar1 ?

Comment: I found this method used about twice as much RAM compared to BackgroundWorker. Also my "DoWork" code usually hung the second time of calling, so I have reverted to using BackgroundWorker.

Answer (score 4):

Hey there's a useful tutorial on Dot Net pearls: http://www.dotnetperls.com/progressbar

In agreement with Peter, you need to use some amount of threading or the program will just hang, somewhat defeating the purpose.

Example that uses ProgressBar and BackgroundWorker: C#

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            // Start the BackgroundWorker.
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                // Wait 100 milliseconds.
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                // Report progress.
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
            }
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Change the value of the ProgressBar to the BackgroundWorker progress.
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            // Set the text.
            this.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
        }
    }
} //closing here
```

Answer (score 2):

There is `Task` exists, It is unnesscery using `BackgroundWorker`, `Task` is more simple. for example:

ProgressDialog.cs:

```
   public partial class ProgressDialog : Form
    {
        public System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar Progressbar { get { return this.progressBar1; } }

        public ProgressDialog()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void RunAsync(Action action)
        {
            Task.Run(action);
        }
    }
```

Done! Then you can reuse ProgressDialog anywhere:

```
var progressDialog = new ProgressDialog();
progressDialog.Progressbar.Value = 0;
progressDialog.Progressbar.Maximum = 100;

progressDialog.RunAsync(() =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000)
        this.progressDialog.Progressbar.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(() => {
            this.progressDialog.Progressbar.Value += 1;
        }));
    }
});

progressDialog.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: In this code, where do I put my long running task?

Comment: @SteveW in RunAsync