# Update main GUI display using another thread or vice versa

Tags: c#

I am new to C# .My job is to do an application which performs a task from step 1 to step 3 and show a GUI in front with info about the progress logged in it.Now i have the below options which would be the best and how can we do that in background.

```
1. Run the form (consisting of a rich text box) in background thread and put the  task     process in main.
2.Run the form in main pgm and put the task as a function running in background.
```

Which of the above is the best approach. OR is there any thing better than the above . How can it be accomplished easily?

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen a GUI, that'd be controlled by a background thread because it needs to be responsive - event handling is being done on a main thread. In winforms for .net 4.0 you've got a `BackgroundWorker` class, with a `ReportProgress()` method raising proper event, which can be attended in your main form (most common use is to draw a progressbar) - that's the simpliest approach.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

[Similar topic on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12127025/1284902)

Comment: Do u mean to have the form as the main thread and the task in the background thread implemented using backgroundworker

Comment: Yes, I do. Keep it simple as it can be.