# Progress Bar not Shown

Tags: c#

I m having a windows form class frmProcessSalary and inside setProgress method is implemented.

```
public partial class frmProcessSalary : Form
{
    public void setProgress()
    {
        int i;

        progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
        progressBar1.Maximum = 200;

        for (i = 0; i <= 200; i++)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = i;
        }
    }
}
```

From another class outside I create a reference to this and call this method.

```
frmProcessSalary newProcessSalary = new frmProcessSalary();
newFrmProcessSalary.setProgress();
```

In this outside class I have hundreds of queries being executed while calling this `frmProcessSalary` method. But the progress bar does not proceed.

I tried with `Application.DoEvents()` also but no success.

Any idea please?

Comment: I agree with Thorsten, I just wanted to suggest this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126889/how-to-use-winforms-progress-bar for you to know how to properly use the progress bar, background worker async, etc..

Answer (score 1):

if you are running the queries in the main thread the UI will not response till the work is done. Try to use a BackgroundWorker.

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
bw.DoWork += DoWork;
bw.ProgressChanged += SetProgress;
bw.RunWorkerAsync()
```

In DoWork you have to call

```
bw.ReportProgress(percent)
```

Comment: What is this bw.ReportProgress(percent) about.Please detail

Comment: It's being done in a separate thread, so you have to report the result to the UI thread which shows the progress bar

Comment: The ReportProgress-Method triggers the ProgressChanged event and passes the progressvalue (a percentvalue) as a parameter. So in the SetProgress EventHandler you get the value to set in your progressBar.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setProgress()
           {

            int i;

            progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
            progressBar1.Maximum = 200;

            for (i = 0; i <= 200; i++)
            {
                progressBar1.Value = i;
                Application.DoEvents();
            }

        }
```