# How to run the Progress Bar with Percentage while datatable binding in Windows Application

Tags: c#

When Fetching the data from database and bind the data as table in between time,How to show Progress Bar in Windows Applications.
I have little confusion about Thread and BackgroundWorker.

Any one tell me sample code for running Progress Bar with Percentage at the same time fetch the data from database.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126889/how-to-use-winforms-progress-bar

Answer (score 0):

For Progress Bar you need to do following steps

> 1. Set ProgressBar.Minimum=1
> 2. Set ProgressBar.Maximum=dataTable.rows.count
> 3. Set ProgressBar.Step = 1
> 4. Apply foreach loop on datatable rows that contains data as

```
foreach (Datarow row in datatable.rows)   
 {    
    prgBarRemittance.PerformStep();  
 }
```