# C# Progress bar with function taking arguments

Tags: c#, progress-bar

I have made a program which takes some files, renames them to a random number and then saves it to a different folder. I managed to make the code do what I wanted, however the files it handles are sometimes quite large and take a while. This means the users sometimes think that the program has crashed.

I would like to add a progress bar to the program, to make it obvious that it's still working and not crashed.

I had a look at [another question on how to add a progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126889/how-to-use-winforms-progress-bar), however in my case the function takes an intake, which depends on the button the user clicks.

I'm unsure how I could add it into my code. Ideally I could have the `backgroundWorker_DoWork` take an additional input, so it would be `(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e, string[] Files)`, but it doesn't seem to be possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The code for the relevant functions is below:

```
private void blindSelected_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> toBlind = new List<string>();
        // Find all checked items
        foreach (object itemChecked in filesToBlind.CheckedItems)
        {
            toBlind.Add(itemChecked.ToString()); 
        }
        string[] arrayToBlind = toBlind.ToArray();

        blind(arrayToBlind);
    }

    private void blindAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> toBlind = new List<string>();
        // Find all items
        foreach (object item in filesToBlind.Items)
        {
            toBlind.Add(item.ToString());
        }
        string[] arrayToBlind = toBlind.ToArray();

        blind(arrayToBlind);
    }

    private void blind(string[] files)
    {
            // Generate an integer key and permute it
            int[] key = Enumerable.Range(1, files.Length).ToArray();
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int[] permutedKey = key.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToArray();

            // Loop through all the files
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
            {
                // Copy original file into blinding folder and rename
                File.Copy(@"C:\test\" + files[i], @"C:\test\blind\" + permutedKey[i] + Path.GetExtension(@"C:\test\" + files[i]));
            }            

            // Show completed result
            MessageBox.Show("Operation complete!", "Done!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your code, I would suggest using `async/await`, you can google for details on how it works. With those you can only change your `blind` function like this:

```
private async Task blind(string[] files)
{
        // Generate an integer key and permute it
        int[] key = Enumerable.Range(1, files.Length).ToArray();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int[] permutedKey = key.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToArray();

        // Loop through all the files
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
        {
            // Copy original file into blinding folder and rename
            // Notice, this will wait for the Task to actually complete
            await Task.Run(() => File.Copy(@"C:\test\" + files[i], @"C:\test\blind\" + permutedKey[i] + Path.GetExtension(@"C:\test\" + files[i])));
            someProgressBar.PerformStep(); // Or just set value by yourself
        }            

        // Show completed result
        MessageBox.Show("Operation complete!", "Done!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

This will guarantee you that `blind` function will run asynchronously. Don't forget to add `someProgressBar` though.

This has some downsides about not being able to throw exceptions up, so make sure you handle them well inside `blind` function - check for not being able to copy file etc.